# Check for duplicate instances of class by their attributes

Tags: python, oop, equality

I'm writing an engine that creates poker hands, and I'd like each hand to contain only unique cards even though I'm drawing from multiple decks

My problem is, this code

```
for z in range(dr):
    if self.cards[-1] not in drawcards:
        drawcards[z] = self.cards.pop()
```

does not register a card with suit x and value y as being equal to another card with suit x and value y

this is my card class:

```
class Card:
    """A class containing the value and suit for each card"""
    def __init__ (self, value, suit):
        self.value = value
        self.suit = suit
        self.vname = value_names[value]
        self.sname = suit_names[suit]

    def __str__(self):
        #Irrelevant

    def __repr__(self):
        #Irrelevant
```

how can I make my program register card a with suit x and value y as equal to card b with suit x and value y?

Edit:
For people looking at this question in the future, in addition to `__eq__`,

```
def __hash__(self):
        return hash((self.value, self.suit))
```

is necessary for the equality specified in the for loop to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define `__eq__` on your class to handle the comparisons. Here are the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__). You'll likely also want to implement `__hash__` as well. The docs talk more about that.

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    # Protect against comparisons of other classes.
    if not isinstance(other, __class__):
        return NotImplemented

    return self.value == other.value and self.suit == other.suit
```

Comment: Remember that `other` can be of any type.

Comment: Thanks @cglacet, I edited my answer to account for that.

Comment: This `__eq__` implementation is majorly broken. I'll take the liberty to fix it.

Comment: @Aran-Fey it would be more helpful to me (and likely others) to explain why your suggestions are preferred rather than come across condescending.

Comment: I don't think your edit was warranted. If you plan on inheriting from this class you will need to make a decision on whether to use `self.__class__` or `__class__`. Using `__class__` will still resolve back to the parent class in subclasses while `self.__class__` will be the class that was instantiated. Then the difference between return False or raising NotImplemented is again personal preference based on the scenario.

Comment: Well, feel free to roll back.